# ContentFrame.Navigate works for navigation items but not AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app with a NavigationView. I have been referring to this documentation which has working samples for everything except more in depth usage of the AutoSuggestBox. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/navigationview

What I am trying to attempt is to update the ContentFrame of the MainPage NavigationView on a QuerySubmitted, I've attempted to do this with a ContentFrame.Navigate, however, this just ends up with the ContentFrame going completely blank. I am very confused as there is not much out there about AutoSuggestBox to go by that's relevant.

My current code looks like this:

```
private async void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmittedAsync(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    searchResultsClass.searchQuery = suggestBox.Text;
    Debug.WriteLine(searchResultsClass.searchQuery);
    await searchResultsClass.SearchAsync();
    this.ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SearchResults));
}
```

SearchResults.xaml, which is identical to my other working views:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.Views.SearchResults"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <GridViewHeaderItem Content="Search results for ''" FontSize="36"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reproduce your issue on my side. `ContentFrame.Navigate` can work well with [`QuerySubmitted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted) event handle. The `AutoSuggestBox` is as follows in XAML:

```
<NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
    <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="ASB" QueryIcon="Find" QuerySubmitted="ASB_QuerySubmitted"/>
</NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
```

And  the result:

[image]

So that please add a break-point on  `this.ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SearchResults));` code line, and to debug your project to check if it can go through successfully to this step .
If you still have issues please upload a minimal reproduced project.

**Updated**

For testing you project, the issue comes to be that the `SearchResults` page lacks of the constructor method. For example:

```
public SearchResults()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
public async Task SearchAsync()
{
   ...
}
```

By default, each navigation creates a new instance of the specific Page (or subclass) requested, and disposes the previous page instance.  Details please reference [`Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) class. So that create an instance `SearchResults` in the `MainPage` in your code snippet may make no sense and will not have influences with the showed navigated `SearchResults` page.

If you want to pass the text of the `AutoSuggestBox` to another page you should **[Pass information between pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#3-pass-information-between-pages)** by the navigate method.

Comment: Alright thanks, I added a breakpoint, seems to be going through fine, still didn't do anything. I created a new project to reproduce the issue and slimmed it down to try and get rid of anything that could be doing it, but still, the same problem. Here's a link to said minimal project, I've probably missed something incredibly obvious,

Comment: Sorry, internet took ages to upload the project to Google Drive. [Here's the link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BihjN8PVnJXzxO86YG30BA556nZLWQKx/view?usp=sharing) Continuing the last sentence before I got interrupted by edit times, I've probably missed something incredibly obvious, apologies if I have.

Comment: @Mtngoats by testing comes to the reason, please check the updated answer.